# How to add a number on the end of another number

Tags: c#, .net

I want to join a number to another number instead of adding it.

Example: instead of `1 + 1` making `2`, I want it to make `11`.

The only thing I think I can do is `+ 1`, but that just makes it `2`, and I want it to make it 11.

Comment: What are you even asking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you want this:

```
1 + 1 = 11
```

Rather than:

```
1 + 1 = 2
```

To do this, just cast the numbers to string and concatenate them. Then you can convert the result back to a number.

```
string result = 1.ToString() + 1.ToString(); // or, "1" + "1"
result == "11";
int numberResult = Convert.ToInt32(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid string instantiation and conversion by using exponentiation and logarithms:

```
public static int Concat(int x, int y)
{
    return x * (int)Math.Pow(10, Math.Floor(Math.Log(y, 10)) + 1) + y;
}
```

This works by multiplying `x` by a power of 10 that has exactly as many zeros as `y` has digits, then just summing `y` onto it. Mathematically: *x* × 10<sup>⌊log<sub>10</sub>*y*⌋ + 1</sup> + *y*.

This will lead to a result whereby the decimal representations of the two numbers appear to have been concatenated.
For example:

```
Concat(1, 1)      :  1 *     10 +     1
Concat(3, 54)     :  3 *    100 +    54
Concat(28, 999)   : 28 *   1000 +   999
Concat(76, 84215) : 76 * 100000 + 84215
```

If you know that your numbers will typically be small, you can write hot paths to avoid the computationally expensive `Pow` and `Log` operations:

```
public static int Concat(int x, int y)
{
    if (y < 10)     return x * 10 + y;
    if (y < 100)    return x * 100 + y;
    if (y < 1000)   return x * 1000 + y;
    if (y < 10000)  return x * 10000 + y;

    return x * (int)Math.Pow(10, Math.Floor(Math.Log(y, 10)) + 1) + y;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to add it multiple times in your code, its better to create a function like this:

```
public static int JoinNumber(int x, int y)
{
    int z = 0;
    string temp = Convert.ToString(x) + Convert.ToString(y);
    z = Convert.ToInt32(temp);
    return z;
}
```

or

```
public static int JoinNumber(int x, int y)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(x) + Convert.ToString(y));
}
```

You need to create overloads for long and other types as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

All you want is:

```
string result = String.Concat(1, 1);
```

really, that's all.

If for an obscure reason you want to go back to an integer value:

```
int result = Int32.Parse(String.Concat(1, 1));
```

beware of overflows.