# How can i add another number to end of current number? LUA

Tags: lua

Hello i want exactly same think like here but in LUA language

[How to add a number on the end of another number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35822810/how-to-add-a-number-on-the-end-of-another-number)

"
I want to join a number to another number instead of adding it.
Example: instead of 1 + 1 making 2, I want it to make 11.
The only thing I think I can do is + 1, but that just makes it 2, and I want it to make it 11.
"

Can you please help me how to do it in LUA?Is any better way that that 6years old answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution :

```
   function JoinNumber(x, y)       
   local z = tostring(x) .. tostring(y);
   return tonumber(z);
   end

   local actionID = JoinNumber(action[2],Config:GetSpec())
```